# jquery: Inner Click not working

Tags: jquery, click, live

Inner click not working **.Html** and **JS** scripts are below .I used `Click` event and then `live` event for inner element click but its not working

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <a style="cursor: pointer" id="abc" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com"></a> 
    <a style="cursor: pointer"id="myLink">Click ME -Open google on new Tab</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#myLink').click(function () {


             $('#abc').click();

        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do.?

Comment: live() is deprecated and removed, but all you're really doing is preventing the click, what are you expecting to happen ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using jquery 1.8.

As of jQuery 1.7, the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is deprecated. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

[Refer here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

`$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {});` replaces `.live()`.

`$('selector').on('event', 'selector', function() {});` replaces `.delegate()`.

`$('selector').on('event', function() {});` replaces `.bind()`.

## But,

Still what are you trying to do?

```
$('#abc').on('click', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want to detect click on multiple id's,

```
 $('#abc, #myLink').on('click',.......
```

should be enough. The outer click detection doesn't seem to be of any use.

Comment: $('#abc').on('click', function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();
            });

Comment: @Shailesh Yes that should work.

Comment: I also tried  <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#myLink').click(function () {


            $('#abc').click();

        });
    </script>  but not working

Comment: First Click working but inner click not

Comment: How do you know your "outer" click is working? And you cannot put another .click within a .click. That would never work, until they are on the same element(may work on same).

Answer (score 1):

Both `click` and `live` attach an event handler to an element, so your code is just assigning a new click handler to `#abc` every time `#myLink` is clicked.

**EDIT after OP's Edits:**

I'm not exactly sure what your are trying to do, but it looks like you want to follow the link for `#abc` when `#myLink` is clicked? The code you have now will do that.

`#myLink` has no `href` attribute and so there is no click to follow.

If you only want to be able to click `#myLink` to follow `#abc`'s href, but not be able to click on `#abc` directly, you could do the following:

```
$('#abc').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#myLink').on('click', function() {
    var abc = $('#abc'),
        that = $(this);

    that.attr({
        "href": abc.attr('href'),
        "target": "_blank"
    }).click();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aE8rR/1)**

Also, the `live` function was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9. You should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

It was already answered, live() is deprecated, but this works like a charm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#myLink').on("click", function () {
        $('#abc')[0].click();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I realised later, what you are trying to do,

Click just triggers the click event / events not the actually "goto-the-links-href" action.

You have to write your own handler and then your **`$('#myAnchor').trigger('click');`** will work...

```
$("#myLink").click(function(event)
{
  var link = $(this);
  var target = $('#abc').attr("target");

  if($.trim(target).length > 0)
  {
    window.open($('#abc').attr("href"), target);
  }
  else
  {
     window.location = $('#abc').attr("href");
  }

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

OR javascript,

```
window.location = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href
```